# Efficient Data Structure for adding/removing from start and end and should support random access

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

It should be efficient to 
- add at start/end
- delete at start/end
- support random access

Comment: There are easily a hundred options, depending on your priorities, the available languages/libraries, etc.  Simplest is a doubly linked list, but random access is slow.

Comment: Do you need a persistent data structure, or will an ephemeral one do? If you need persistence, random-access lists or finger trees will be necessary. The simpler array-based implementations are fine if an ephemeral structure will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Double the size when you run out of space. This will perform insert/delete at start/end as well as random access in O(1) time per operation (amortized).

In C++, std::deque can do insert/delete at start/end as well as random access in O(1) .

Answer (score 3):

**[Finger Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree)**.  Hinze, Ralf; Paterson, Ross (2006), "Finger Trees: A Simple General-purpose Data Structure", Journal of Functional Programming 16 (2): 197–217.

- *O(1)* access to add/delete to start/end.
- *O(log n)* random access.

Looks a bit like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Purely Functional Random Access Lists](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5156) by Chris Okasaki. Similar to Hinze's finger trees.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a homework question, so avoiding spoonfeeding until clarified.

Have a look at some of the [abstract data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Abstract_data_types). From there you can decide which data type suits your requirements and choose an appropriate data structure implementation.

Comment: OK maybe a further pointer: Double-ended queues (`deque`s) have the same requirements; it so happens that a particularly common (and simple) implementation of this type will do `O(1)` for all the operations you describe.